# How to resolve Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function?

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error in my javascript code. It worked fine when I was working on the chart and maps separately. But the moment I integrated these two it stopped working.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geomap']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);
    var test;

    function drawMap() {
        var test1 = {{pie2008|safe}}
        var test2 = {{pie2009|safe}}
        var test3 = {{pie2010|safe}}

        console.log(test1);
        console.log(test2);
        console.log(test3);
    }

    function drawMap2008() {
        console.log("In draw map function");
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{data2008|safe}});
        var options = {};
        options['region'] = 'US'
        options['dataMode'] = 'regions';
        var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
        console.log(data);
        geomap.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawMap2009() {
        console.log("In draw map function");
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{data2009|safe}});
        var options = {};
        options['region'] = 'US'
        options['dataMode'] = 'regions';
        var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
        console.log(data);
        geomap.draw(data, options);
    }

    function drawMap2010() {
        console.log("In draw map function");
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{data2010|safe}});
        var options = {};
        options['region'] = 'US'
        options['dataMode'] = 'regions';
        var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
        console.log(data);
        geomap.draw(data, options);
    } 

    function drawChart2008() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{pie2008|safe}});
        var options = {
          title: 'Maximum Facebook users for 2008',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };      
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    function drawChart2009() {
          console.log("In draw map function");
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{pie2009|safe}});
        var options = {
          title: 'Maximum Facebook users for 2009',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };      
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

      function drawChart2010() {
          console.log("In draw map function");
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{pie2010|safe}});
        var options = {
          title: 'Maximum Facebook users for 2010',
          pieHole: 0.4,
        };      
        var container2 = document.getElementById('donutchart');
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container2);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="handb">
    <h3>No of facebook users per state</h3>
    <button id="data2008" onclick = "drawMap2008()">Intensity Map for 2008</button>
    <button id="data2009" onclick = "drawMap2009()">Intensity Map for 2009</button>
    <button id="data2010" onclick = "drawMap2010()">Intensity Map for 2010</button>
    <button id="pie2008" onclick = "drawChart2008()">Pie chart for 2008</button>
    <button id="pie2009" onclick = "drawChart2009()">Pie chart for 2009</button>
    <button id="pie2010" onclick = "drawChart2010()">Pie chart for 2010</button>
  </div>
  <div id='map_canvas'></div>
  <div id='donutchart'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am not understanding why I am getting this error. I am getting this error in the drawchart2008 function on the line -
 var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion would be that `chart.draw(data, options);` is not actually a function (`.draw()` is not a method on the type `chart`).
Just because .draw() exists on `geomap.draw(data, options);` does not mean that it does for `chart`.